# recurrence relations solving with two recursive calls

Tags: algorithm

I do not know which method is best to solve this recurrence, since it has two recursive calls.

> Show that the tight solution to the recurrence
>
> T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> is T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)
>
> (use any method you want).

Also in general, how to determine what is the asymptotic for recurrence relations?

Answer (score 0):

one of the best way you can solve this recurrence by recursion tree.
You can make recursion tree which will look like as.

[image]
so on .
The most shallow branch of the recursion tree is the leftmost branch. Its length is log3n.
The deepest branch of the recursion tree is the rightmost one, and its depth is log3/2n.
On each level of the tree the total size of the sub problems is at most n.
as at level 2 sum is  n/3+2n/3=n and at level 3 sum is n/9+2n/9+2n/9+4n/9=n.
the additive term in T(n) is n^2 and thus T(n)>= nlog(n) hence T(n)=theta(n^2).
hope u got this.

Comment: Can you please provide a picture. that would be more clear. thank you.

Comment: just try to make one i will add the picture.

Comment: thanks. the n^2 does not  effect the logn? also should not the root be n^2? just to understand more